# Как посчитать одинаковые значения в массивах?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть несколько одномерных массивов. Как посчитать одинаковые значения в массивах?

```
    $array1 = array(
        "pass" => false
    );
    $array2 = array(
        "pass" => true
    );
    $array3 = array(
        "pass" => true
    );
```

**Обновление**

Во втором и третьем массиве `"pass" === true`, то есть на выходе я должен получить массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pass_false] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [pass_true] => 2
        )
)
```

**Обновление**

Пока додумался только обеденить все массивы в один и по `while`

```
$i = 0;
$i_end = count($arrayAll);
while ($i < $i_end) {
    if ($arrayAll[$i]["pass"] == 1) {
        $array2[]["pass_true"] = +1;
    } else {
        $array2[]["pass_false"] = +1;
    }
    $i ++;
}
```

Но пока так и не додумался как посчитать их...

Comment: уточните вопрос.

Comment: Что значит "одинаковые значения"? Значения под одним и тем же ключом? А если массивы будут `['a' => true]` и `['a' => ['a' => true]]` - значения одинаковые (`true === true`)? Или разные (`true != ['a' => true]`)? А если под разными ключами (`['a' => true]` и `['b' => true]`)? Опишите задачу точнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение может не самое элегантное, но рабочее

```
$arrayAll = array(
    "1" => $array1,
    "2" => $array2,
    "3" => $array3,
    "4" => $array4
);

$arrayComplate = array(
    "pass_true" => "0",
    "pass_false" => "0"
);

$i = 1;
$i_end = count($arrayAll);
while ($i <= $i_end) {
    if ($arrayAll[$i]["pass"] == 1) {
        $arrayComplate["pass_true"] ++;
    } else {
        $arrayComplate["pass_false"] ++;
    }
    $i ++;
}
```